# Java - how to store a (multi-child) tree in file?

Tags: java, file-io, data-structures, tree

I'm working on an [open-source, cross-platform](https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/BlackPomodoroApp) pomodoro timer with statistics support.

For tasks, I have a tree data structure like this:

```
class Task {
    String name; 
    int minutesWorkedOn;
    int uniqueID;
    Task parent;
    ...
    ArrayList<Task> childTasks; //Note, not binary, but can have n-children.
}
```

*(which is actually a [bit bigger](https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/BlackPomodoroApp/blob/master/BlackPomodoroApp/src/dataStructures/Task.java) in practice)*

I want to store this data structure in a file between sessions.
I was considering JSON or xml, and recurse for childTasks, or write all tasks out, one task per line and piece things back together by taskID's. But JSON/XML is not a hard-requirement, I'm just thinking out loud.

Some S.O answers mention serialization, but preferably I'd like to be able to see the stored data structure as is the case with JSON or XML. Also those two formats would make it easier to build reporting tools.

Considering I'm new to java and haven't worked with File/I/O before, can someone give me a tip/advise on which route to take here?

**[edit]**
The solution below works well. There is an issue with loops thou. I edited the code above, a task has a backwards link to it's parent. This causes gson to crash. I might ignore this field and fix it again after the data was loaded or maybe read some more about the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easy way is to use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to write/read the object to a file.

Write:

```
//Get the json serialization of the task object
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
//builder.setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls(); //optional
Gson gson = builder.create();
String json = gson.toJson(task);  
try {  
   //write json string to a file named "/tmp/task.json"  
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/tmp/task.json");  
   writer.write(json);  
   writer.close();  
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Read:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
try {  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/task.json"));  
    //convert the json string from file back to object  
    Task task = gson.fromJson(br, Task.class);  
} catch (IOException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: The solution works well. There is an issue with loops thou. I edited the code above, a task has a backwards link to it's parent. This causes gson to crash. I might ignore this field and fix it again after the data was loaded or maybe read some more about the tutorial, maybe there is a way around it.